# Inspect variable outside of anonymous class in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

is it possible to get the value of a final variable declared outside an anonymous class (where the debugger currently is) in Eclipse?  For example:

```
    final int x = 5;
    new Object() {
        {
            System.out.println(x);
        }
    };
```

This will compile and print "5", but if I try to inspect x on the println line I get the error "x cannot be resolved to a variable".

Comment: This is a known Eclipse [bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=304761).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Expand the "this" item on Variables view; it contains variable val$x where you can see the x and it's value.

Comment: Very cool.  You'd wish there were an easier way?  I also like that if you find a variable in this list and then try to Watch it, you get <error(s)_during_the_evaluation>.

Comment: An "easier way" is that you could set up a watch expression if it's a small handful of variable's you're interested in.

Comment: Hi Rob, I use watch expressions all the time but they do not work well for for variable outside an anonymous class.